# Error: Unclassifiable statement Fortran code

Tags: fortran

I am new in Fortran. I am trying to convert the following python code into Fortran. In the Fortran code I have used a text input file for the z variable but in the Python I have an excel file. Both  files are here: [Excel and txt file](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1ScTAzc2o939DCt8WA0Z6_WX8IAn2kLbQ?usp=sharing)  Here I post both my python and Fortran codes. Python code is running fine but the Fortran is giving me error.

Error log:

```
-------------- Build: Debug in myproject (compiler: GNU Fortran Compiler)---------------

gfortran.exe -Jobj\Debug\ -Wall  -g     -c C:\Users\clhal\Desktop\Demofortran\myproject\xyTuple.f90 -o obj\Debug\xyTuple.o
gfortran.exe  -o bin\Debug\myproject.exe obj\Debug\main.o obj\Debug\xyTuple.o   
C:\Users\clhal\Desktop\Demofortran\myproject\xyTuple.f90:55:4:
     xyz
    1
Error: Unclassifiable statement at (1)
f951.exe: Error: Unexpected end of file in 'C:\Users\clhal\Desktop\Demofortran\myproject\xyTuple.f90'
Process terminated with status 1 (0 minute(s), 0 second(s))
2 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 0 second(s))
```

text data with 24 rows,15 columns:

```
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0.16    0.16    0.17    0.18    0.19    0.19    0.19    0.19    0.18    0.18    0.18    0.18
0   0   0   0.31    0.33    0.35    0.37    0.37    0.39    0.39    0.37    0.37    0.37    0.37    0.37
0   0   0   0.47    0.49    0.52    0.55    0.56    0.58    0.58    0.56    0.55    0.55    0.55    0.55
0   0   0   0.48    0.51    0.55    0.59    0.6 0.61    0.61    0.59    0.59    0.59    0.59    0.59
0   0   0   0.48    0.53    0.57    0.62    0.63    0.64    0.63    0.62    0.62    0.62    0.62    0.62
0   0   0   0.49    0.55    0.6 0.66    0.68    0.69    0.68    0.67    0.67    0.67    0.67    0.67
0   0   0   0.49    0.57    0.63    0.7 0.72    0.73    0.73    0.72    0.72    0.72    0.72    0.72
0   0   0   0.49    0.59    0.65    0.75    0.77    0.78    0.77    0.77    0.77    0.77    0.77    0.77
0   0   0   0.49    0.61    0.68    0.79    0.81    0.83    0.82    0.81    0.82    0.82    0.82    0.82
0   0   0   0.49    0.63    0.7 0.83    0.86    0.87    0.87    0.86    0.87    0.87    0.87    0.87
0   0   0   0.49    0.65    0.73    0.87    0.9 0.92    0.92    0.91    0.92    0.92    0.92    0.92
0   0   0   0.49    0.67    0.76    0.91    0.95    0.97    0.96    0.95    0.97    0.97    0.97    0.97
0   0   0   0.49    0.69    0.78    0.95    0.99    1.01    1.01    1   1.02    1.02    1.02    1.02
0   0   0   0.49    0.71    0.81    0.99    1.04    1.06    1.06    1.05    1.07    1.07    1.07    1.07
0   0   0   0.49    0.73    0.83    1.04    1.08    1.11    1.1 1.09    1.11    1.11    1.11    1.11
0   0   0   0.49    0.75    0.86    1.08    1.13    1.15    1.15    1.14    1.16    1.16    1.16    1.16
0   0   0   0.49    0.77    0.88    1.12    1.18    1.2 1.2 1.19    1.21    1.21    1.21    1.21
0   0   0   0.49    0.77    0.88    1.12    1.18    1.2 1.2 1.19    1.21    1.21    1.21    1.21
0   0   0   0.49    0.77    0.88    1.12    1.18    1.2 1.2 1.19    1.21    1.21    1.21    1.21
0   0   0   0.49    0.77    0.88    1.12    1.18    1.2 1.2 1.19    1.21    1.21    1.21    1.21
```

Here are the codes:

Python code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

#read the growth rates in z
z = pd.read_excel(r'D:/Shuvashish/Oyster Shaye/growth rate look up table.xlsx', 
                  dtype={'Oct':object},sheet_name='growth_z', header=None)
# put salinity in x
x = [] 

for i in np.arange(0.0, 36, 2.5):
    x.append(i)
    
#  put temp in y    
y = [] 

for i in np.arange(12.0, 36, 1):
    y.append(i)    
    
xy = [(i, j) for i in x for j in y]

#create xyz tuples
xyz = [(i, j, z[x.index(i)][y.index(j)]) for i in x for j in y]
```

Fortran code:

```
program readdata
! Include the necessary libraries
use, intrinsic :: iso_fortran_env

implicit none

! Define user-defined types
type xy_tuple
  real :: x
  real :: y
end type xy_tuple

type xyz_tuple
  real :: x
  real :: y
  real :: z
end type xyz_tuple

! Declare variables
integer :: i, j, k
real :: x(15), y(24)
integer :: nrows, ncols
character(len=255) :: filename
real :: z(15,24)
type(xy_tuple), dimension(360) :: xy
type(xyz_tuple), dimension(360) :: xyz

! Set the text file name
filename = 'D:/Shuvashish/Oyster Shaye/growth_z_for_sal_tem.txt'

! Open the text file
open(10, file=filename, status='old')

! Read the growth rates from the text file into the z array
do i = 1, 15
  read(10,*) (z(i,j), j=1,24)
end do

! Close the text file
close(10)

! Create the x and y arrays
x = [(i * 2.5, i=1,15)]
y = [(i, i=12,35)]

! Create the xy array
do i = 1, 15
  do j = 1, 24
    xy((i-1)*24+j) = xy_tuple(x(i), y(j))
  end do
end do

! Create the xyz array
do i = 1, 15
  do j = 1, 24
    xyz
  end do
end do
end program readdata
```

My ultimate goal is to fit an rbf or idw interpolation for the xyz data. Then I will fed the model with xy values it will give me the z values. In python I can achieve it in the following way:
from sklearn.preprocessing import PolynomialFeatures
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression

```
from scipy.interpolate import Rbf, NearestNDInterpolator
data=xyz
# Assume `data` is a list of tuples in the format (x, y, z)
X = [(t[0], t[1]) for t in data]
y = [t[2] for t in data]

# Fit an RBF interpolation to the data
rbf = Rbf(*zip(*X), y)

# Evaluate the RBF interpolation at all input the data points
z_pred_rbf = rbf(*zip(*X))

# Evaluate the RBF interpolation at a new data points
x_new = 11
y_new = 18
z_new = rbf(x_new, y_new)
print('growth rate using rbf: ', z_new)
```

Comment: It looks like you don't have a complete source file. It simply stops part way through a line, part way through a loop, part way through a program. Are you sure that's all you've written? See [mre]. You code really does just stop, entirely incompl

Comment: Sorry for being clueless. I am a complete beginner in Fortran and that's what I could figure out to create an xyz array.

Comment: It's not the problem of being a beginner, your code is obviously incomplete. Even as a beginner you can se

Comment: Maybe xyz((i-1)*24+j)=xyz_tuple(x(i),y(j),z(i,j))

Comment: Please do not share the input file in external storage sites like Google Drive. If it is a text file, just copy and paste the relevant part of the file right here into your question as text. Use [edit] to add the data now. It is very important, the question must remain valid also in the future and the files in external sites often get deleted.

Comment: @ZVY545, you are trying too hard to make Fortran look like python. X and Y arrays have equal spacing, so you don’t need entities like xy_tuple and xyz_tuple. Just construct your interpolation straight on the array z(i,j).

Answer (score 2):

Taking the hint from @lastchance in comments, I have modified your code which runs without error for me. See if this helps. I would have just commented but don't have enough reputation.

```
program readdata
! Include the necessary libraries
use, intrinsic :: iso_fortran_env

implicit none

! Define user-defined types
type xy_tuple
  real :: x
  real :: y
end type xy_tuple

type xyz_tuple
  real :: x
  real :: y
  real :: z
end type xyz_tuple

! Declare variables
integer :: i, j, k
real :: x(15), y(24)
integer :: nrows, ncols
character(len=255) :: filename
real :: z(15,24)
type(xy_tuple), dimension(360) :: xy
type(xyz_tuple), dimension(360) :: xyz

! Set the text file name
filename = 'growth_z_for_sal_tem.txt'

! Open the text file
open(10, file=filename, status='old')

! Read the growth rates from the text file into the z array
do i = 1, 15
  read(10,*) (z(i,j), j=1,24)
end do

! Close the text file
close(10)

! Create the x and y arrays
x = [(i * 2.5, i=1,15)]
y = [(i, i=12,35)]

! Create the xy array
do i = 1, 15
  do j = 1, 24
    xy((i-1)*24+j) = xy_tuple(x(i), y(j))
  end do
end do

! Create the xyz array
do i = 1, 15
  do j = 1, 24
    xyz((i-1)*24+j) = xyz_tuple(x(i),y(j),z(i,j))
  end do
end do
end program readdata
```

Comment: Deb, sorry, it doesn't give me what I want. In the debugger I can see it doesn't produce the result.

Comment: @ZVY545 what does mean "it doesn't produce the result"? Please be more specific instead of expecting us to guess. I you mean that it does not produce the *expected* result, then it is no longer related to the question, which was about a compilation error. Looks like the question has been answered.

Comment: Agree with @PierU that Deb S. B. has answered the question as originally asked. What “result” do you want? There’s a hint in your other post that you want your array in a different order - but that’s a misunderstanding in your original reading of z(i,j), not the construction of a 3-d point as here.